# How to modify the view of the string in dropDownList?

Tags: yii2

I've got a table

```
| id|title|parent|
|---|-----|------|
| 1 | ABC | null |
| 2 | DEF |   1  |
| 3 | GHI | null |  
|----------------|
```

I prepare data for dropDownList

```
$a = Model::find()->select('id, title, parent')->all();
$b = ArrayHelper::map($a, 'id', 'title');

<?= $form->field($modelForm, 'parent')->dropDownList($b); ?>
```

When I choose 'parent' ('parent' has a foreign key to 'id') I see next list:

```
ABC
DEF
GHI
```

But I want something like that to see in dropdown list:

```
ABC
DEF => 1
GHI
```

or

```
ABC
DEF (1)
GHI
```

What should I do to add parent column to the name of the proposed string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just change this line.

```
$b = ArrayHelper::map($a, 'id', function($model){
  return $model->title.'=>'.$model->parent;
});
```

OR

```
$b = ArrayHelper::map($a, 'id', function($model){
  return $model->title.'('.$model->parent.' )';
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I also added 'if' to check null values.